# Execute 2 tasks for a specific amount of time (Python)

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to print out "Hello World" for 3.5 seconds.

```
import time

t_end = time.time() + 3.5
while time.time() < t_end:
    print("Hello World")
```

After that time, another text should be printed out automatically for 3.5 seconds. How can I make an infinite loop here?

Comment: Can you clarify your problem a bit? What you mean by "make an infinite loop here?" Where is "here"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
import time

while True:
    print("Hello world!")
    time.sleep(3.5)
    print("Hello again!")
    time.sleep(3.5)
```